# Why does this simple Tkinter tutorial script run fine on Raspberry Pi, but not on MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

The following is a small python3 script from a web tutorial that demonstrates how to make pulldown menubars using Tkinter.

It is copied directly from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_menu.htm with no changes!

- It works fine when I run it on a raspberry pi (using 3 different IDEs)
- BUT when I run it on my Mac (in 2 different IDEs) it just creates the white window and places no menu elements into it.
- NOTE that this Mac is able to run other simple Tkinter scripts that I have been making as I try to learn Tkinter... making buttons, popups, no problem.

New Edit: When I go to the macs that this is failing on, and I do:

```
    >>> import tkinter
    >>> tkinter._test()
```

...the test works fine with its little buttons etc, and I get the little window telling me it's v8.5.

What is it about this script that is making the mac choke (and the other computer is not)?   Huge thanks!

Here is the tkinter script that fails on the macs:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
def donothing():
   filewin = Toplevel(root)
   button = Button(filewin, text="Do nothing button")
   button.pack()

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save", command = donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save as...", command = donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Close", command = donothing)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Undo", command = donothing)

editmenu.add_separator()

editmenu.add_command(label = "Cut", command = donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Copy", command = donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Paste", command = donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Delete", command = donothing)
editmenu.add_command(label = "Select All", command = donothing)

menubar.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu = editmenu)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label = "Help Index", command = donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label = "About...", command = donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = helpmenu)

root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What versions of tkinter do you have in raspberrypi and macos?

Comment: Hashbang! If this is copied directly from the script, the hashbang identifier is incorrect and will run in the system installation of python, which IIRC for MacOS is Python2, not Python3.

Comment: Hi @Alan -- you know, i thought that also, but when I totally delete the hashbang file when on the mac, the file still will not run right, same "blank white window that still appears to be running its mainloop as it announces it's done when I close it" issue. (and all those other Tkinter scripts that run OK on the mac don't have a hashbang.)

Comment: @eyllanesc -- I will go and try to learn the versions of tkinter.  Embarrassed to say I'm not confident of my way to find out those version numbers in either setting -- I will try now.

Comment: Yes, because the hashbang has a space in it ... so it is being ignored. Try correcting it to `#! /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @eyllanesc  On the mac, I did >>> tkinter.TkinterVersion and the reply was 8.5 ... I will look at the Pi now...

Comment: @eyllanesc  and then I checked on the Pi and the version there is 8.6.  of course this raises the idea that I could update the version on the mac... but I sort of think... that tutorial was probably written quite a while ago, it would be odd to have such a version requirement for a simple tutorial script...   However, i can look at updating the one on the mac

Comment: @estephan500 
It is only to know, if you are comparing the same library on different platforms you should know the versions, have you tried another computer ?, In addition it would be advisable to indicate how you have installed tkinter in macos.

Comment: @eyllanesc and... also... now that I try, I realize I'm not sure how to update it past 8.5... googling it but it seems to be one of those "download this, issue these make commands, then totally update python" things that I'm hesitant to start since ... as I say above, I'd be surprised that a tutorial script this simple would require a specifically recent version of Tkinter...

Comment: @estephan500 
My suspicion is that when you installed tkinter not all the dependencies were installed, have you tried with a simpler script ?, maybe it shows a button or a label, or an entry.

Comment: @Alan ... unfortunately when I took the space out of the hashbang as you suggested, no change whether I run it from PyCharm IDE or if I try to run it from the mac command line.

Comment: @eyllanesc ... I run plenty of other python scripts on this mac, and many are simpler Tkinter scripts I've done while trying to learn it.

Comment: @eyllanesc and all... when I use the standard tkinter test call, it seems to work and shows buttons, etc... on two separate macs that the script fails on, it works OK on both macs, shows the little test buttons etc...  and says v8.5 when I do the following: 
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BUT when I run it on my Mac (in 2 different IDEs) it just creates the white window and places no menu elements into it.

Great, it's working perfectly!

The window itself is *not where menus go* on the Mac - look at the top of the screen, just like every other Mac application.

Comment: HAhahahahahaha!!!  OK, you win!  :)   Thanks much. Not so often that an answer is right in front of me quite like that.   Thanks... this had me going to about 10 different sources... :)   And I got distracted by various reported issues about 8.5 having incompatibility on the mac... and how the mac guidelines rule out certain TK menu functions... when in reality, it was right there.  Thanks! :)